# Using Linux workstations to remote into Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2012 Windows 7 VM

Tags: windows, linux, hyper-v

I am trying to help out a very small business with a cost effective solution, but where users have to remote into their Windows 7 VM to do work so they do not save anything on the local Linux physical workstation. I was thinking about doing the following:

- Image the existing Windows 7 systems and use those licenses to create the VMs on the 
  Hyper-V server
- Remove Windows 7 on the physical workstations and install the free Linux OS like Ubuntu 
  or something comparable
- Then have the users remote into their Windows 7 VM from the Linux workstation at their 
  desks

My question is, is this a possible solution and if so, how would I get the Ubuntu or some Linux variant to remote to the Windows 7 VM?

I will be installing Windows Server 2012 Essentials with Remote Web Access and I wouldn't know how to connect to that via a Linux OS. Could Rdesktop, TSclient, or Remmina do this for me?

Thanks